# Why is Magento 2.1.0 released before 2.0.9?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.0, magento-2.1, semantic-versioning

Magento has released 2.1.0 on June 23 but has released 2.0.8 (July) and 2.0.9 (Aug) after that. (https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases)

Why are they releasing lower versions? If anybody knows the reason, please let me know. I have already upgraded to 2.1.0 and then these new releases are coming.

Comment: I like that question :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Magento2 is following [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/). This means that the versions consist of `major.minor.patch` numbers. Whenever there are bugs or security issues solved, Magento will release a new "patch" version, meaning an increase of the 3rd and last number.

Magento has said to consider every minor release as an LTS (Long Term Support) release. Which means that every increase of the second number does not mean that support for the previous minor version will be dropped.

So, currently we have Magento 2.0.x and 2.1.x as minor versions. Both of them will be supported for a longer period of time, all though newer minor versions have already been released.

The 2.0.8 and 2.0.9 releases solve issues that exist within the 2.0.x releases. Apparently there are no parallel 2.1.x releases, so these issues probably do not exist in the 2.1.x releases (or will be released all at once in 2.1.1 maybe?).

You could expect more releases like this in the future (2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, etc...). Also maybe when 2.2.0 is released, there will still be 2.1.x and 2.0.x releases, until the LTS support of those minor versions will end. As [Ben Marks](/users/5/benmarks) of Magento commented below, the duration of LTS support is 2 years.

Read more about the Magento2 versioning here in the official docs:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/backward-compatibility.html

Alen Kent has also written a nice blog on the versioning, including all the modules (the `100.x.x` system):

- https://alankent.me/2015/10/02/magento-2-version-numbering-update/

Comment: Great answer. Maybe you could slightly enhance it by mentioning that 2.0.10 will follow 2.0.9, to give an example of how the version is increased.

Comment: Duration of LTS for minor marketing versions (e.g. 2.0, 2.1) is 2 years.

Comment: Can you provide citation for "2 years"? I can find no official commitment from Magento to support any version for any period of time, only the stackoverflow comment.

Comment: @josephdpurcell See the comment by Sherrie Rohde and my updated answer on this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141875/3326